# ASP.Net Session Lost if Exception occurred

Tags: asp.net

We develop a web application and when the user loggedin I save the `userID` in the `session["UserID"]` and at the each `page_load` we check the session is null, if so, we log off and redirect to login page.

If an exception occurred and enter to catch block the `session["UserID"]` being NULL and log off the user.

Please help me to know why the session be a null if any exception occurred. and note that all the methods and code we set them in a try-catch block and we write the code to a log file.

Answer (score 1):

We catch the problem, we log the exceptions in a file ( the file stored in a folder called Logfile in bin) , Server.MapPath("Bin")\Logfile\Log.txt.

This is make the session lost because we write the file in the bin folder.

We modify log tracking and save it in logfiles beside bin not in bin and every thing work fine.

Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess it depends on where you are keeping session state and what type of exception is being thrown. If session state is kept inproc then chances are that the exception is causing the web app process to recycle.

#### Suggestion/Question

Why are you using session state to determine whether a user is logged in or not? This is an `ASP.NET` application, right? Which assume it's consumed by browsers, correct? Why can't you use cookies? Cookies are more reliable than session for storing user data (as long as you don't use and abuse it). I would suggest you use cookies rather than session for this purpose.

Comment: OK, But if we use the cookie to check if the user logged in or not and  the cookie is disabled on the client  Explorer it will fail, Right??. the second thing is how to change the sessiob state kept from inproc to another in Visual Studio 2010??. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the user has cookies disabled...well...too bad, he/she should enable it if it wants to login to your web application. All modern sites depend on cookies for user authentication, I've got no idea why you want to do something different. Again, session is not reliable and it is an awful solution. However, if you still insist, you can change how you store session state in the web.config